# My spring boot application doesn't update my JavaScript code, uses the old one

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

I have the following code in my JavaScript:

```
function retrieveObrasSgc(numero, Url) {
    var url = Url + "/tabla"; 
    url += '?page=' + numero + '&search=' + "";

    if(afi !== undefined)
        {

        url+='&idAfiliacion='+afi;
        $("#resultsBlock"+afi).load(url);
        }
    else
        $("#resultsBlock").load(url);
}
```

Before this code we used to have another one that was replaced by this. The problem is that when I run my web page and inspect with Chrome tools it shows the old JavaScript code, and the code that runs is the old code and not this new one (even though we deleted the old one and have only this one now). In other computers works fine, the problem is mine.

My Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.21</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing place a "?Num=1" (change the number) at the end of the address for the javascript file. Your browser will think its a new file since the address is different. For the production just remove the extra bit at the end of the address

For example

../../../MyJavascriptFile.js

becomes

../../../MyJavascriptFile.js?Variable=Something

This will make the browser think the file is new. You can increment the variable number each time you make a change, alternatively you could just delete all the browsers offline files, which will force the file to be downloaded

Comment: That does not work because it uses the old JavaScript file (the one I deleted), so never goes inside my new JavaScript code.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. Your browser is using the cached version. If you add "?Num=1" the end of the address the address is different so will not use the cached version and will instead load the new file

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I totally misunderstood you because i didn't know that was possible haha, thanks a lot its working now, any idea why its this happening only in my computer?

Comment: To speed up loading most browsers don't download pre cached files for some time. Ive been working on some CSS files where I had the same issue. Couldn't figure out why my styles weren't changing.

Answer (score 0):

try holding CTRL and then press F5

```
CTRL+F5
```